# How to reinstall TeamViewer trial version on linux after its expiry?

Tags: linux

The TeamViewer7 trial version is currently installed on my Ubuntu linux system. It has expired. How do I clear the registry. How do I change the settings 'For personal use' for the new install which I see in some of the urls which I have come across on the net. Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamViewer bundles its own version of Wine, so all you have to do is delete the directory you extracted it to. All its settings are kept in "teamviewer7/.wine".

Answer (score -2):

Best way ist to BUY the full version of TeamViewer.

Comment: It's free for personal use.